# CMD Batch File to Read Files in Directory and Create new files with Content from the Name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

If I have a directory with 2 files in it like these:
123456789_File1.pdf
123456789_File2.pdf

I need to run a batch file that lets me read the name of the file only and not it's path.  Create another file with the same name and a different extension with a contents that is only the first 9 characters of the name.  Below is what I have tried and I cannot figure out why this is not correct?  I have done several hours of research over something that seems like it should be simple and I feel like I am just missing something.

```
FOR /R C:\Test\Files %%F in (*.*) do (set content=%%~nF & echo %content:~0,9%>> %%~nF.txt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R . %%F in (*.*) do (
    set content=%%~nF
    echo !content:~0,9! %%~nF.txt
)
```

For future reference, please note that "this is not correct" is not an accurate description of the problem as far as StackOverflow questions and answers are concerned. The precise description of your problem is that in each iteration of the loop, `%content%` appears to contain the exact same content as it had in the first iteration of the loop, regardless of the value of `%%F`.

The solution is to enable "delayed expansion" and to use the special `!` delimiter instead of `%` so as to enjoy the benefits of delayed expansion.